# python twice as fast than pypy reading/iterating a file

Tags: python, performance, pypy

Usually, for regular simple python code, using pypy will be faster.  But how come when I am reading a file and just splitting string and doing very simple logic, it is much slower than regular python.

Take the following code for reference.

First lets create a fake file using the code below:

```
NUM_ROWS = 10000000
FILENAME = "testing.txt"

def create_file():
    data = []
    for x in range(NUM_ROWS):
        data.append("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH II JJ KK LL MM NN OO\n")

    with open(FILENAME, "w") as f:
        for d in data:
            f.write(d)
        f.close()
```

This just creates a file called `testing.txt`.

Then we have a `sample.py`:

```
import datetime
FILENAME = "testing.txt"

start = datetime.datetime.now()
with open(FILENAME) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        data = line.split(" ")
        if data[0] != "AA":
            print(i, line)
print(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

Doing `C:\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\pypy3.exe sample.py` takes `42s` while `python sample.py` takes `18s` only

I am using python3.7 on a windows 10 machine.  Is there a way to speed up such a simple script like the above using pypy?  Am I using it wrong?

----------Update:

Apparently its the 'reading' or iterating through the file that is slow in pypy.

With sample.py as:

```
import datetime
FILENAME = "testing.txt"

start = datetime.datetime.now()
with open(FILENAME, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        pass
print(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

I tried with latest pypy3 build as of 20200818.  Here are my findings regarding the simple code above (just plain iterating line by line of a file with 10 million lines).  In Windows, regular python (3.8) takes 2.3 secs for the above code to execute and with pypy3 it takes an awfully slow 30 secs.  In Ubuntu, regular python takes 1.2 secs and takes 3.4 secs with pypy3.  The linux version is definitely more acceptable, but the windows definitely need some work

Is there a way to speed up reading/iterating the file with pypy for windows?

Comment: Sorry forgot '\n', I updated my question.  Either way, pypy is still slower

Comment: I would recommend making the test more specific. Your example is reading from a file, splitting a short string and probably never print anything? Perhaps just read files as one example. And another that just splits a string. `timeit` can also be useful.

Comment: It doesnt really matter whether it prints something or not.  As long as the 2 tests are the same.  My point really is that why is pypy slower than python, where it normally is the other way around.  Will try to profile further

Comment: Try `if not line.startswith("AA "):`?

Comment: The reason for making the test more focused is so that it gives you an idea what actually is slower. Which will then also be helpful for people with a better understanding of how pypy works.

Comment: I updated the question above, removing opening/iterating the file made the pypy faster.  Still wondering how I could make pypy faster by reading/iterating the file

Comment: Can you try with the nightly builds from https://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/py3.6/ ?  We improved the file reading performance by some factor, but it would be interesting to know if and how much slower pypy3 remains here.

Comment: Tried the latest one there, dated 20200818.  Still same.  Just iterating the file line by line using pypy is 10x slower than just using python

Answer (score -2):

the question was updated, so I update my answer :

as with every optimisation, You need to profile each part.
Of course You should focus on the commands in the loop.

my solution (without profiling) to pass the same tests would be :

```
import datetime
FILENAME = "testing.txt"

start = datetime.datetime.now()
with open(FILENAME) as f:
    i = 0
    data = f.readline()
    while data:
        if not data.startswith('AA '):
            print(i, line)
        i += 1
        data = f.readline()

print(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

however, that was not the solution @user1179317 expected
in the updated question @user1179317 is now aware that the reading of the file data chunks is the issue.

You can try to read the data in chunks, using yield :

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
    """generator to read file in chunks"""
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data


with open('big_file.data') as f:
    for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
        process_data(piece)
```

---

Another option would be to use iter and a helper function:

```
f = open('big_file.dat')
def read_chunk(chunk_size=1024):
    return f.read(chunk_size)

for piece in iter(read_chunk, ''):
    process_data(piece)
```

again - this is not a `ready to use past & copy`answer - You need to profile and test, since the results will depend on file size, available ram, maybe block size of the harddisk, maybe IP packet sizes, etc ...

Since that operation is I/O bound, a multi-threaded approach might be good - You might try to read the next chunk of the file in a seperate thread.

So - You need to profile with different chunk sizes

Comment: This solution is still slower using pypy

Comment: I did not say that this will be faster. This is only the first step, to move out as much as possible from the loop. Now You need to profile each command. 
Look at file buffers, etc ... that might have an impact. 

The with statement handles opening and closing the file, including if an exception is raised in the inner block. The for line in f treats the file object f as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered I/O and memory management so you don't have to worry about large files.

Comment: These very simple lines are 10x slower on pypy, which is not doing anything but iterating the file:                                                         
 with open(FILENAME) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        pass

Comment: Got it, I will try.  sorry for the misunderstanding